# Android Cordova - how to run Cordova web view from service and pass some data to the app JS interface?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, service

I have written Cordova plugin (service, which is watching calls time in background) I would like after each time is receiver triggered run Cordova activity and pass some data in JSON into app (get data in JS code of the Cordova app).

How can i do it please?

I spent a few hours by searching any tutorial for this, but without luck.

Thanks for any help.